# What is the meaning of "guy who invented pants"?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2

In the X-Mansion, Deadpool says to Colossus:

> You'd think the studio would throw us a bone. One that doesn't end up in my mouth. The first movie made more money than the **guy who invented pants**. They can't just dust off one of the famous X-Men?

What is the meaning of "guy who invented pants"?

Comment: Jeans? Could he mean Levi Strauss.

Comment: He means "*The guy who invented a thing that is so ubiquitous that everyone has it*", like "*the guy who holds the patent for fire*"

Comment: I don't get all the downvotes. It's a short and simple question, but it's well stated and I can see how one might not understand the line

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Trousers (pants) are very popular: most people own a pair.

The person who first comes up with an idea (these days) usually gets a patent on the idea, to allow them time to recoup their investment in developing the idea into a product.

If you have a patent on something that means no-one else can make it without paying you for the rights to do so.

If the person who invented trousers had a patent on them, given their popularity, they would have an exclusive and very lucrative business.

**So "the guy who invented pants" would have a lot of money.**

Deadpool is saying the original film made a lot of money.

It's hyperbole, if for no other reason than trousers have been around longer than recorded history, so the person who "invented" trousers wouldn't have made any money.

Comment: Had to upvote for the first sentence alone.

Answer (score 7):

It's just a throwaway joke to describe the fact that the previous movie made a lot of money.

If you assume that inventing something nets you royalties in all cases (it doesn't), then the longer something's been around, the more money it will have made it's inventor.

Pants have been around a REALLY long time [to the tune of fifteen or more centuries](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trousers#History) so in concept if you invented pants you've earning a ton of royalties.

All that said, the inventor of pants is not known, and that's not really how royalties work, but it was a fun bit of hyperbole and Deadpool is using an absurd metaphor (as he frequently does) to get some laughs out of us.